# ListView with complex items, how to know the state of items?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
  android:layout_height= "fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/DictLink" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
<CheckBox android:text="" android:id= "@+id/DictTitle" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
```

It used as Item in ListView. Code below create a array adapter for ListView.

```
ArrayList< HashMap< String, String >> adapter_list = new ArrayList< HashMap< String, String > >();

    for ( String dict : dict_list )
    {
      String [ ] data = dict.split( ";" );
      HashMap< String, String > adapter_entry = new HashMap< String, String >();
      adapter_entry.put( FIELD_TITLE, data[ 0 ] );
      adapter_entry.put( FIELD_LINK, data[ 2 ] );
      adapter_list.add( adapter_entry );
    }

    String [ ] from =
    { FIELD_TITLE, FIELD_LINK };
    int [ ] to =
    { R.id.DictTitle, R.id.DictLink};

    final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( this, adapter_list, R.layout.dict_list_item , from, to );
```

How can I know which checkboxes are checked and which not?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` class has functions that will help you:

`int ListView.getCheckedItemPosition()` (for single-selection lists)
`SparseBooleanArray ListView.getCheckedItemPositions()` (for multi-selection lists)

And more:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds()

Comment: If I set list_view.setChoiceMode( ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE ); SparseBooleanArray returns to me 12 false, but I checked 2 items. Probably I need to connect ListView with checkbox on LinearLayout id/DictTitle but how to do that?

Comment: Make sure that selecting the checkbox also triggers performItemClicked on the ListView item, as this function is what actually changes the checked state internally.